# How VBA plot area resize does not work correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize plot areas of all three charts I created in a spreadsheet using the following code (see below). The problem is that "Left" of those plot areas look quite different even I am using the exactly the same numbers (left0=20). I have spent a few hours online finding some solutions. But no success so far.

A little more background: I have three charts lined up vertically. These charts are exactly the same in size. I want to align all the Y axes in the same vertical line (see picture).See those bottom two charts. Their Y-axes are not aligned with that in the first chart (Top chart; I used a red vertical line to delineate Y-axis of the first chart;).

[image]

The first and third charts were created using `xlColumnClustered`, and the second one was created using `xlLine`. Y axes use different `.TickLabels.NumberFormat` (generic, %, and dollars), though.   Thanks!

```
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Selection.Width = width0 '
Selection.Left = left0 '12.1
Selection.Top = top0 '2
Selection.Height = height0 '220
```

Comment: I tried to post a screen shot. But not sure how to achieve it. This website doesn't appear to allow you to insert a picture.

Comment: Thanks, BigBen! Finally figured out how to insert a link to an image to the post.

Comment: What does `Selection.Left` give you back after you set it to `12.1`, and do the plot areas have enough space within the chart to move to the right?

Comment: @GSerg, I changed it to different numbers. It appears the plot area did adjust accordingly. It seems different charts take the same "Left" number differently (or somehow the scales are different on different charts, even though my chart sizes are exactly the same).